# Reset counter on window functions

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset like the below and I want to create a new column C that acts like a counter/row number which should get reset every time column B has 0 partitioned by column value of A

Using SparkSQL / SQL only (I can do it using Pyspark)

```
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([
...     [1, 0], [1, 1],[1, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1],
...     [1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 1], [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1]])
>>> df = rdd.toDF(['A', 'B'])
>>> 
>>> df.show()
+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
|  1|  0|
|  1|  1|
|  1|  1|
|  1|  0|
|  1|  1|
|  1|  1|
|  2|  1|
|  2|  1|
|  3|  0|
|  3|  1|
|  3|  1|
|  3|  1|
+---+---+
```

What I would like to achieve

```
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  0|  1|
|  1|  1|  2|
|  1|  1|  3|
|  1|  0|  1|
|  1|  1|  2|
|  1|  1|  3|
|  2|  1|  1|
|  2|  1|  2|
|  3|  0|  1|
|  3|  1|  2|
|  3|  1|  3|
|  3|  1|  4|
+---+---+---+
```

What I have so far

```
>>> spark.sql('''
...    select *, row_number() over(partition by A order by A) as C from df
...    ''').show()

    +---+---+---+
    |  A|  B|  C|
    +---+---+---+
    |  1|  0|  1|
    |  1|  1|  2|
    |  1|  1|  3|
    |  1|  0|  4|
    |  1|  1|  5|
    |  1|  1|  6|
    |  3|  0|  1|
    |  3|  1|  2|
    |  3|  1|  3|
    |  3|  1|  4|
    |  2|  1|  1|
    |  2|  1|  2|
    +---+---+---+
```

Comment: You need a column that specifies the ordering of the data.

Comment: That will be Column A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You need a column that specifies the ordering of the data.

With such a column you can accumulate the `0` values because they appear to be breaks.  So:

```
select df.*, row_number() over (partition by A, grp order by A) as C
from (select df.*,
             sum(case when b = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by A order by <ordering column>) as grp
      from df
      ) df
```

Comment: Wow. Could you please throw some light on how this grouping works!

Comment: @Bala . . . It is doing a cumulative sum of the rows with a `0` count.  That defines the grouping you want for the `row_number()`.  You can run the subquery to see the intermediate results.